# ruby: howto use multiple boolean options and keep the code readable

Tags: ruby

I need to process a couple of boolean options, and I am trying to do it like it is usually done in C:

```
  DICT    = 0x000020000
  FILTER  = 0x000040000
  HIGH    = 0x000080000
  KEEP    = 0x000100000
  NEXT    = 0x000200000
```

I can now assign arbitrary options to a Integer variable, and test for them:

```
action if (opts & HIGH|KEEP) != 0
```

But this looks ugly and gets hard to read. I would prefer writing it like

```
action if opts.have HIGH|KEEP
```

This would require to load `have` method onto `Integer` class.

The question now is: where would I do that, in order to keep this method contained to the module where those options are used and the classes that include this module? I don't think it's a good idea to add it globally, as somebody might define another `have` somewhere.

Or, are there better approaches, for the general task or for the given use-case? Adding a separate `Options` class looks like overkill - or should I?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`anybits?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Integer.html#anybits-3F-method):

```
action if opts.anybits?(HIGH|KEEP)
```

The methods returns `true` if any bits from the given mask are set in the receiver, and `false` otherwise.